# CSS selector last element

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am working with a `HTML` document that looks like this.

It contains several `<li></li>` elements. At the moment it contains two. But it is dynamic in nature and it can be more.

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('li.lia-paging-page-last>a')[1].getAttribute('href'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="lia-page">  
    <li class="lia-component-pagesnumbered">
      <ul class="lia-paging-full-pages">
        <li class="lia-paging-page-last lia-js-data-pageNum-39">
          <a class="lia-js-data-pageNum-109 lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event" aria-label="Page 39" id="link_8" href="abc.com">129</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lia-component-pagesnumbered">
      <ul class="lia-paging-full-pages">
        <li class="lia-paging-page-last lia-js-data-pageNum-49">
          <a class="lia-js-data-pageNum-109 lia-link-navigation lia-custom-event" aria-label="Page 49" id="link_77" href="xyz.com">229</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to query the `href` of the last `<li></li>` element. Is there a CSS selector I can use that can return the last element?

Currently, I am doing this and hardcoding the length-1 as [1] to select the last element. I want to bypass that, if there is a way to use a CSS selector that can always return the last element of this.

`document.querySelectorAll('li.lia-paging-page-last>a')[1].getAttribute('href')`

I also, tried the following and it did not work.

`document.querySelectorAll('li.lia-paging-page-last>a:last-of-type').getAttribute('href')`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's (misspelled) word soup. See [ask].

Comment: Also, your list markup is invalid. List items must be children of a list.

Comment: Your second attempt would select the last _anchor_ in the list item. That's not what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question and it is part of an actual website and I was trying to replicate the part which was giving me trouble, edited the mark-up to mock the actual. Also, I could not make the reference post solve the issue.

Comment: `li.lia-paging-page-last:last-child a` or `ul.lia-paging-full-pages li:last-child a`

Comment: This worked for me `document.querySelector('div>li:last-child a').getAttribute('href')`.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for :last-child

Comment: I tried `document.querySelectorAll('li.lia-paging-page-last>a:last-child')` and it did return what I needed.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @connexo how so? I told him the solution and it worked. how is that not an answer?